# Google cloud speech to text API - text output contains spaces or hyphens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

In the Google cloud speech to text API whenever the user speaks the number or read out the number like `9500456765` the converted text that comes out is `9500 456 765`.

There are spaces in between the numbers or even hyphens like `9500-456-765`.

Is there a way to get the number same as the user had spoken without any spaces or hyphens?

Comment: We hit the Google speech to text API by making a post call along with API key generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell speech API to disable this splitting of numbers. What you can do is to detect this in text and post process the text output to remove these spaces and hyphens.
What I do in python when result is number is this,

```
result.replace(' ','').replace('-','')
```

Comment: Is this a write practice of doing it? I believe Google cloud API should give a toggle switch / any feature to do this. Any attributes for enabling the same? They hv something called speech context where you can insist on the word/pharse that spech API should consider while converting speech to text? Anything on the similar lines would help though

Comment: Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.